# How can I redirect back from https to http URLs after I removed a SSL certificate of lets encrypt in apache2 & nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, wordpress, apache2, lets-encrypt

I configured a certificate of let's encrypt using certbot-auto and the https worked but when I was trying to remove the certificate of my domain using certbot-auto delete... my wordpress and phpmyadmin site stopped being recognized, it keeps redirecting to https and it gives an error 404 can't reach this page but the apache2 and nginx index page could be reached...

I already did all of that cleared the cache, history, cookies, checked the mysql database it's on http:// but still redirects it to https:// and says it can't reach the page... I need to check for something in the deeper level, but I don't know what to check I tried to delete the ssl.confs that were made by let's encrypt but still 0 results

I need help re-configuring my servers back to the http redirect from the https redirect of the certificate configuration What are the processes needed to be done in order to turn it back to http redirect? Thanks for your help...

Comment: You should change your Apache configuration.

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev thanks for the reply, where are the files needed to be configured and which configuration do I need to put there in order for http to work?

Comment: Have you updated the value of WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL in the WordPress database?

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu thanks for your reply, yes I did it's http:// and I even changed it by myself to http:// to make sure

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for their effort to help...
I found the problem... there was a redirection in the nginx default in sites-available and in apache2 000-default.conf
I deleted it and now everything works
if it can help someone else I would be very glad

Comment: Thanks for sharing what went wrong. Please explain a bit more to be more helpful for others. For example, does default.conf belong to nginx or apache? Please be sure to mark your answer as the correct answer too.